# MVC4 RedirectToAction returns HTTP 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My RedirectToAction returns HTTP 404, except the controller, action and view are there, spelled correctly with proper caps.  I am in SubscriberController and I want to call an action in CreateTestController.

Here is my initial url:

```
http://www.localdomain.com/Subscriber/AuthUser
```

This launches the page which has several forms in it, the one I'm using for this call is below:

```
<form id="btnform7" action="LaunchTestPortal" method="post">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" id="antiforge7" type="hidden" value="rzTdAi...aj501">
    <button title="Create, Edit or Review Training" class="ui...active" id="btnLaunchTestPortal" role="button" style="width: 13em; height: 22px; margin-bottom: 10px;" type="submit">
        <span class="ui-text-only">Create, Edit or Review Training</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

this successfully calls this method in the SubscriberController

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LaunchTestPortal()
{
    return RedirectToAction("CreateTestPortal", "CreateTest");
}
```

This is the method I want to call in CreateTestController

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ViewResult CreateTestPortal()
{
    ...
}
```

after the call, this is the address it returns `http://www.localdomain.com/CreateTest/CreateTestPortal`

except the page result is HTTP 404  not found.
All the parts are there.  It just the redirect in controllerA won't call the method in controllerB

Comment: I think it needs to be RedirectToAction("CreateTestPortal")

Comment: No, if I do that, it tries to send it to "Subscriber/CreateTestPortal",  but I need it to send it to "CreateTest/CreateTestPortal"

Comment: Just to clarify, if you POST to http://www.localdomain.com/CreateTest/CreateTestPortal directly, does it also fail? This would indicate that you have a routing issue.

Comment: yes, when I post the form directly to localdomain/CreateTest/CreateTestPortal, it finds it and launches it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I put comments in the for my changes, so that you can learn.

```
public class SubscriberController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Subscriber/
    public ActionResult AuthUser()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LaunchTestPortal()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("CreateTestPortal", "CreateTest");
    }
}

public class CreateTestController : Controller
{
    //removed two attributes
    public ViewResult CreateTestPortal()
    {
        var ap = "dh";
        return View();
    }
}
```

AuthUser.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AuthUser</title>
</head>
<body>
    @*added Subscriber below*@
    <form id="btnform7" action="/Subscriber/LaunchTestPortal" method="post">
        @*changing next line*@
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @*<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" id="antiforge7" type="hidden" value="rzTdAi...aj501">*@
        <button title="Create, Edit or Review Training" class="ui...active" id="btnLaunchTestPortal" role="button" style="width: 13em; height: 22px; margin-bottom: 10px;" type="submit">
            <span class="ui-text-only">Create, Edit or Review Training</span>
        </button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CreateTestPortal.cshtml

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>CreateTestPortal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```